# PHP Curl Randomly Hangs

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I wrote a PHP script that curls URLs to get the page html.  The page content comes back about 50% of the time and the rest of the time only part of the content is returned and the script fails to terminate.  I'm not getting any errors...

```
$headers = array(
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkN6ktadXpZl_viwRCSEGUQ');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $response;
print_r($curl_info);
```

Run on CLI:

```
php script_name.php
```

If ran 10 times or so you will see that it is unable to complete at least a few times with no warnings or errors...

Comment: are you running this on windows or a linux?

Comment: I'm asking because on Windows the time spent to download the page is considered execution time, see http://php.net/set_time_limit

Comment: Same thing from the command line...  curl 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkN6ktadXpZl_viwRCSEGUQ'

Comment: Sometimes there nothing at all when running the CLI tool, other times it's incomplete and hangs, then sometimes it just works...

Comment: Something in my OS must be messed up...  After a restart curl CLI tool is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu had performed a bunch of system updates.  I was working with the code when the updates finished.  After a system restart this issue went completely away.  Go figure.